# How to make smth after AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I have an ajax call which returns a string and creates a `<span>` element with a string in it. Then I want to add some class to a newly created `span`. But due to asynchronous nature of AJAX, function that adds class executes BEFORE the AJAX call.

So, should I use deferred promises? How?

**Little simple code is in** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samosfator/52U3j/3/)**.**

**Expected result:**
*Click to buttons gets the response and adds class to span*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pass the callback function as a parameter to your `get()`:

```
$('button:eq(0)').click(function () {
    get(function () {
       $('span').addClass('red');
    });
});
```

And in `get()`:

```
function get(callback) {
    //more code
    .done(function (result) {
            //even more code
            callback.call();
        });
};
```

---

Deffered object alternative is to return `$.getJSON()` promise from `get()` and add classes in its `.done` callback:

```
function get() {
    return $.getJSON( // more code
}

$('button:eq(0)').click(function () {
    get().done(function () {
       $('span').addClass('red');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/52U3j/2/

Here, i've fixed your class css too.
You put:

```
span.red {color:green}
```

and was a mistake :)

it has been changed to

```
span.red {color:red}
```

**REMEMBER!**

Ajax is an asynchronous call, so the code you want to execute **ONCE COMPLETED** the request, **CAN'T** go after the call, but **It has to be written only inside the callback** called once done.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't looking for a solution like yours... It isn't good idea to store all functions in `.done(function (result) {}` I wanted to see an example of using callbacks.

Comment: You don't have to store ALL FUNCTIONS inside the .done, just what you need to get to your purpose. But It's fine, on this site you ask something, wait for answers and use the most suitable one for you :)